# API test MongoDB nodes express ec2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, amazon-ec2

I have created app with nodejs, express and mongodb, when I test the API using Postman I get `Hello world!`. But when I add collection to API URL I get this error:

```
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5b0aecbd-61a0-4cd6-a197-f04f37df5198
Host: XXXXXXXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

The server code is:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.send("Hello World!");
    });
    
    app.get("/users", function() {
      MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
        if (err) next
        db
          .collection("users")
          .find()
          .toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
    
            res.json(result)
          });
      });
    });
    
    app.listen(3000,function(){
        console.log('Express app start on port 3000')
    });
```

What could be causing the error?

Mongodb shell version is 3.6.8
Node version is 17.3

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add req and res arguments in the /users endpoint

It should be like this

```js
app.get("/users", function(req, res) {
```

and you do not have a next function in your code

```js
if (err) next
```

Comment: thank you David for your response what I have to do here "and you do not have a next function in your code"?

Comment: You are trying to call a function called next, but you don't have a function with that name. To fix it you can create a function with next name or just throw err instead of calling next.